# How can I export a single Excel sheet to a PDF file using Applescript?

Tags: excel, macos, pdf, applescript

Here is the code I am working with:

```
saveExcelasPDF("Users:Seth:Documents:OneDrive:Process:12648 0920 Volvo of the Triad 128.xlsx", "Users:Seth:Desktop:test.pdf")

    on saveExcelasPDF(documentPath, PDFName)
        set tFile to (POSIX path of documentPath) as POSIX file
        tell application "/Applications/Microsoft Excel.app"
            set isRun to running
            set wkbk1 to open workbook workbook file name documentPath
            activate object worksheet "Invoice" of wkbk1
            set mySheet to sheet "Invoice" of wkbk1
            alias PDFName -- Necessary to avoid Excel Sandboxing
            save mySheet in PDFName as PDF file format
            close wkbk1 saving no
            if not isRun then quit
        end tell
    end saveExcelasPDF
```

Right now, it saves every sheet in the desired book to the PDF file, so I end up with a PDF with about 60 pages..

How can I save only the "Invoice" sheet to my PDF file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug with the `PDF file format`.

The `save` command works correctly when the format is `CSV file format` as an example.

A work around is:
Copy the sheet to a new workbook.

```
on saveExcelasPDF(documentPath, PDFName)
    set tFile to (POSIX path of documentPath) as POSIX file
    tell application "/Applications/Microsoft Excel.app"
        set isRun to running
        set wkbk1 to open workbook workbook file name documentPath
        set newWBK to make new workbook
        copy worksheet (sheet "Invoice" of wkbk1) before sheet 1 of newWBK
        close wkbk1 saving no
        alias PDFName -- Necessary to avoid Excel Sandboxing
        save (sheet 1 of newWBK) in PDFName as PDF file format
        close newWBK saving no
        if not isRun then quit
    end tell
end saveExcelasPDF
```